# Reading entity properties in generic repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm writing a simple logging mechanism for my app.

I have generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity>:IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal Equipment_TestEntities context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    internal Log entry;

    public GenericRepository(Equipment_TestEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        this entry= new Log();
    }
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
        AddLog("insert "+typeof(TEntity)+" "+entity.ToString());
    }
    private void AddLog(string action)
    {
        entry.Action = action;
        entry.Date = DateTime.Now;
        string username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        username = username.Substring(username.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        entry.Who = 1;
        context.Logs.Add(entry);
    }
}
```

In `entry.Action` I want to keep:

1. Action eg. Insert
2. Which entityUsed eg. User or Role
3. Something to identify entity

In 1) I can easily hardcone action
2) I can use `TypeOf` and get entity class name

But in 3rd I have a bit problem. 
In case of insert I can ask db for the newest record but what should I do in Edit/remove cases?
Is there any ways to get properties value from those entities?

@Update:

sample part from unitOfWork:

```
public IRepository<Storage> storageRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.StorageRepository == null)
            {
                this.StorageRepository = new GenericRepository<Storage>(context);
            }
            return StorageRepository;
        }
    }
```

IUnitOfWork:
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
         IRepository storageRepository { get; }
    }

Comment: Why not create an interface for your entities (`where TEntity : IEntity`) and then define an Id property in that interface?

Comment: How should it look if not all entities/tables in Db have Id/PrimaryKey?

Comment: There's something smelly with your code... I mean you are not using dependency injection correctly and btw private fields should (but not must) start with underscore - this is a naming convention and in constructor try to avoid writing `this`. You should rather write something like `_context = context;` and sorry I don't know the answer for your question.

Comment: @szpic I think sroes is correct. If not all have primary key? Can't you make the field nullable for those cases?

Comment: @rosko what do You I'm not using DI correctly? I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Those two lines: `this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();` and `this entry= new Log();`. I'm not into EF so I can't really tell that first one is totally wrong in your case but `Log` should be passed as a constructor parameter. Anyway anytime you see that there is `new()` in your code then it's obvious that you are not using DI correctly.

Comment: Ah. Yes. Log is there temporary while checking how to manage to get needed data for log.

Comment: @rosko To your point about szpic's naming conventions - there is absolutely nothing wrong with `this.variable` vs `_variable` - as long as you're consistent (e.g. `this.dbSet` should be used instead of just `dbSet` in this case).

Comment: @rosko DI is being used. Just because you see new() in one place does not mean DI is not being followed, it just means there is a hard reference to Log which may be acceptable. Now if something that was passed in to the constructor was not being set as readonly property and then being changed to something else later, that would be a violation of DI

Comment: @rosko I hate underscores too :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an interface for the entities:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int? Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the generic constraint:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity>:IRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can simply use entity.Id to identify your entities.:

```
public virtual void Remove(TEntity entity)
{
    if (!entity.Id.HasValue) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot remove " + entity + ", it has no ID");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: But this throws: `Error 2 The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>' 
`

Comment: Now this destroys my unitOfWork: `Error 5 The type 'magazyn.Models.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'magazyn.DAL.GenericRepository<TEntity>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'magazyn.Models.User' to 'magazyn.DAL.IEntity'. 
`